# onTaskRemoved() not affecting variables?

Tags: android

I found a way to know when an app goes to background (its task removed). I created a `Service` that start as **non-sticky** and overrided the method:

```
  public class myService extends Service {

     ...

     @Override
     public void onTaskRemoved(Intent rootIntent) {

        NotificationsListenerTask.isAppInBackground = true;
        Log.d("TEST", "background");

        stopSelf();

    }
  }
```

Where `NotificationsListenerTask.isAppInBackground` is a **static boolean** that's located in another class and set to false by default.

I have another `Service` that start as **sticky** and prints the value of `NotificationsListenerTask.isAppInBackground` every 5 seconds.

The problem is, after the app is killed (and I see that `onTaskRemoved` is called because the `Log.d` that I set appeared), the value of `NotificationsListenerTask.isAppInBackground` **does not change**! It keeps printing the old value every 5 seconds...

Why doesn't it change, and how can I make it change (or how can I notify the other Service that onTaskRemoved was called)?

Comment: `onTaskRemoved()` is not guaranteed to be called. Maybe [here](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/35729654/whi%D1%81h-function-is-called-when-application-is-removed-from-task-manger) you might find some help.

Comment: This is called when I need it (I can see it in the Log cat)... But for some reason the boolean "isAppInBackground" does not change and I don't know why

Comment: If a process has been terminated by OS, you have...nothing! in memory. When OS starts it again later `isAppInBackground` will be set to a default value.

Comment: Going into the background and being killed are two different things.  If your other service is running in the same process, it will also be killed.  If it's running in a different process, it has its own independent copy of the static variable.

Comment: But even setting a sharedPreferences value did not work! How can I notify my other Service then?

Comment: look at here : http://stackoverflow.com/questions/24127923/service-ontaskremoved-not-called-if-started-with-bindservice